# How to Manage Multiple Express Router to Redirect One Another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am using Express.

I ran into an issue that I cannot redirect from one route folder to the other route folder.
To explain further, I have app.js and routes folder in the same place.

This is my app.js routes middleware

```
app.use(homeRoutes);
app.use('/blog', apiRoutes);
```

I have a middleware for get request as below

```
// in routes/homeRoutes.js
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/blog');
});
```

this is supposed to be linked to

```
// in routes/apiRoutes.js
router.get('/', blogController.blog_index);
```

and

```
// in controller
const blog_index = (req, res) => {
    Blog.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        .then(result => res.render('index', { blogs: result, title: "List" }) )
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

However, I am getting 404 error.
But when I moved below code into app.js, it works.

```
// in routes/homeRoutes.js
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/blog');
});
```

I would like to know how to make it work in two separate routes files.
So that I can organize and make my project as clean as possible.

Kindly let me know its solution and any other advice that you could give me.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in routes/homeRoutes.js you should write this

```
const express = require('express);
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/blog');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I put that in routes/homeRoutes.js, and it did not work

Comment: i added app.js file. since the i was having the reported issue, i commented ```app.use(homeRoutes);``` and made routes in app.js

Comment: From review: @keppodon you've clicked the wrong edit button. Please edit the post to provide more details of your app instead of trying to put them in an answer. Thanks.